# Use my iMac as a Bluetooth headset for my BlackBerry

Tags: mac, bluetooth, blackberry, headset

Is there a way to use my iMac as a Bluetooth headset for my BlackBerry?

(Using the speaker and microphone or my mac as output/input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mac would have to support the 'headset' bluetooth profile which it doesn't.

Comment: And there is no way around it?

Answer (score 2):

bluephone elite does it for mac
http://mirasoftware.com/BPE2/

Comment: well it has been discontinued